# Running different stacks on same cloud instance

Tags: php, python, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I'm running a Python-based application on an AWS instance but now I want to install a Wordpress (PHP) blog as a sub-domain or as a sub-folder as an addition in the application. Is it technically possible to run two different stack applications on a single cloud instance? Currently getting an inscrutable error installing the Wordpress package with the Yum installer.

Comment: Yes you can run python and php on the same instance.

Comment: please include the command and error result.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run it on the same physical server, you can run it on an EC2 server the same way. There is no difference as far as that is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to look at [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). It would allow you to easily package and distribute your applications. You would be able to logically separate your `php`, `python` stacks.